# hover not working for items in list

Tags: jquery, list, hover

Honestly not sure what I'm doing wrong- I want to add a highlight effect on hover for items in a list. The html is below:

```
    <div class="list">
        <h3 id="mainlist">YOUR LIST:</h3>
        <input type="text" class="newitem">
        <div class="additem">ADD</div>
        <ul></ul>
    </div>
```

And what I have of jquery is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.additem').click(function() {
        $('ul').append('<li class=listitem><span>' + $('.newitem').val() + '</span></li>');
    });
    $('.listitem').live ('click',function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
    $('span').hover(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('hover');
    });
});
```

Everything works until the toggleClass part, nothing seems to happen when I hover over things. It's not a browser issue, the hover works fine with other html elements that aren't inside the list. I have also tried changing 'span' to 'li' instead, but that didn't work either.

Would really appreciate any help with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is CSS' job! If all what a `hover` handler is doing is toggling a class , so do it like this:

```
<style>
  li.listitem span:hover{
  /* CSS Rules */
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

just do:

```
<style>
  li.listitem span:hover{
  /* some CSS */
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Uh? seems like you've copypasted someone else' answer?

Comment: what's new in this ? Cherniv already answered the same before

Comment: Cherniv's answer came like 20 seconds before mine

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.additem').click(function() {
    $('ul').append('<li class=listitem><span>' + $('.newitem').val() + '</span></li>');
 $('span').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
 });
});
$('.listitem').live ('click',function() {
    $(this).remove();
});

});
```

Basically you are assuming that the "hover" event handler will be attached to the spans even when they were not in the dom. You must attach an event to the element after it has been created.

Comment: But one thing... You should opt for the css solutions for such problmes.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what went wrong! The css solution works better, but this helps me figure out where I was messing up. I appreciate it too. :D